# IPC_RMID not work on linux with C++

Tags: c++, linux, ipc, semaphore

I'm trying to solve my school project in C++. I have to create 15 processes and they have to run in order what means that processes run in this order 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 0. It work but when I try to remove semaphore from the memory I am getting error from semctl. On the end I use "semctl(semid, 0, IPC_RMID, 0" but I get error 22 which means EINVAL but it doesn't make sense and I try to remove semaphore from parrent process so I should have privileges to do that.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/sem.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

union semun {
            int val;
            struct semid_ds *buf;
            ushort *array;
                 };
struct sembuf sops[1];
int semid;

 int wait_sem(int index, int pid){
       fprintf(stderr, "\n------- Proces %d do operation wait (-1) on semaphore %d\n",pid, index);
                  sops[0].sem_num = index;
                  sops[0].sem_op = -1;
                  sops[0].sem_flg = 0 ;
     if  (semop(semid, sops, 1)<0){
             perror("semop fail wait");
             return 1;
         }
         else
             return 0;
  }

 int signal_sem(int index, int pid){
      fprintf(stderr, "\n++++++ Proces %d vykonava operaciu signal (1) na semafore %d\n",pid,index);
            sops[0].sem_num = index;
            sops[0].sem_op = 1;
            sops[0].sem_flg = 0;
     if  (semop(semid, sops, 1)<0){
            perror("semop fail signal");
            return 1;
         }
         else
            return 0;
  }

 void createSem(key_t paKey, int paSemFlg, int paNsems)
 {
     printf ("uid=%d euid=%d\n", (int) getuid (), (int) geteuid ());
     (semid = semget(paKey, paNsems, paSemFlg));


     for (int i = 0; i < paNsems; ++i) {
         semctl(semid, i, SETVAL, 0);
     }
 }

 void kic()
 {
     printf("\naaaaaaaaaaaaaa\n");
 }

 int  main() {

          key_t key = 1234;
          int semflg = IPC_CREAT | 0666;
          int nsems = 15;
          int semid;
          fprintf(stderr, "%d=", sops);
          createSem(IPC_PRIVATE, semflg, nsems);
        if (semid == -1) {
            perror("semget: semget failed");
        return 1;
        }
        else
            fprintf(stderr, "semget: semget sucess: semid = %d, parrent pid %d\n", semid, getpid());


   int PROCESS_ID = 0;
   pid_t PID;

   for (int i = 1; i < nsems; i++) {
       PID = fork();
       if(PID == 0)
       {
           PROCESS_ID = i;
           break;
       }
   }

   if(PID == -1)
   {
       printf("\nPID ERROR");
   }

   if(PID != 0) //parrent
   {
       printf("\n\nparrent with ID %d", PROCESS_ID);
       signal_sem(PROCESS_ID+1, PROCESS_ID);
       wait_sem(PROCESS_ID, PROCESS_ID);
       printf ("uid=%d euid=%d\n", (int) getuid (), (int) geteuid ());
       printf("\nEND %d\n", getpid());
       int s;
       wait(&s);

       if((semctl(semid, 0, IPC_RMID, 0))==-1)
       {
           int a = errno;
           printf("\nERROR IPC_RMID %d\n", a);
       }
   }

   if(PID == 0)//child
   {
       if(wait_sem(PROCESS_ID, PROCESS_ID) == 0){
           printf("\nI am child with ID %d", PROCESS_ID);
           int ID_NEXT_PROCESS = 1+PROCESS_ID;
           if(ID_NEXT_PROCESS == nsems)
               ID_NEXT_PROCESS = 0;
           signal_sem(ID_NEXT_PROCESS, PROCESS_ID);
           return 0;
       }

   }
    return 0;
  }
```

Comment: Looks more like C than C++, but as you explicitly asked about C++: Do not add C tag for C++ questions.

Comment: Either the processes run simultanously or they run in a specific order. You cannot have both.

Comment: sorry for my mistake I meant in order :) and all my code runs in c++ but this is example of my code not all my code :) the rest of my code is not important right now

Answer (score 1):

You have two `semid`s. One in global scope, another local to `main` (which shadows global, you should see a warning). `createSem` only knows about global one, and initializes it. `semctl` is called directly by `main`, and is passed the local one, which is garbage.